# quicker way to damp track or track to a location?

Tags: modeling

[image]

If i am rigging/modelling, i often have the need to align (track to, rotate) an object to a location.

e.g. : the blue part track to the 3D cursor.

I solve this by giving the blue part an object constraint (damped to) the piston (with of course setting the origin of the piston to the 3d cursor), then apply.

But this sounds a bit complicated to me. Is there a quicker way (and i am pretty sure there is)?

Something like "track to 3D cursor" e.g.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Something like "track to 3D cursor" e.g.?

Wouldn't that be nice?  At first sight, a 'Point ±XYZ at 3D Cursor' operator would  seem a great addition to the Snap menu.   And not so hard to implement? Maybe a rock-solid Pythonista will answer this question with one :)

In the mean time, there is an 'Insta-Track' to Active Object. It's in the <kbd>K</kbd> *Track* sub-menu of the *Header > Object* menu. It can be added, as here, to your Quick Favorites:

[image]

It adds an 'Auto-Track' in the constraints tab, where 'Up' and 'Axis' can be adjusted.

Comment: ok...this is nice, but if somebody has an even nicer solution, i will change my "right answer" flag ;)

Comment: @Chris Absolutely! Fair enough! I'm tempted to have a shot at writing the operator myself, but I'm very slow at it, and not fully acquainted with all the possible 'gotchas'.

Comment: Thank you for that Robin - it’s already an improvement for me anyway!